# Story about a deadly alien creature on another planet that has some chemical in its body that makes it faster

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I can not remember if it was a short story or a novel, but I am leaning towards it being a novel. There is a colony of humans and I can't remember if they crash-landed or not.

There is a creature that they come to discover after it has killed a few people. The creature has some kind of chemical in its body that is like a super-adrenaline. One part is I remember is one of these creatures getting very hot from using up its reserve of this chemical and it dived into a river or pond and it started to steam. Something like that.

It has to be at least 10 years since I read the story.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Colonists kill local creature, only to discover they were killing off immature monsters](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142303/colonists-kill-local-creature-only-to-discover-they-were-killing-off-immature-m)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe you are thinking of Larry Niven's [Heorot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Niven#Heorot) books, which includes: [The Legacy of Heorot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legacy_of_Heorot) and [Beowulf's Children](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf%27s_Children).

These stories involve an alien labeled as "grendels", that have a unique ability:

> A grendel can, on demand, release a chemical supercharger into its blood that does to it what nitrous oxide does to internal combustion engines - enable short bursts of speed in excess of a hundred miles per hour. ... The supercharger, when used, generates large amounts of waste-heat that warm up grendel bodies so rapidly they will die after using it if they do not immediately return to water to cool off.

Comment: Nice work. This was one of my favorite Larry Niven, Jerry Pournelle, and Steven Barnes collaborations.

Comment: Thank you! Nice to see that there is a second book as well. Time to get to reading!