# What is the name of this (possibly 40 year old) Sci-Fi novel

Tags: story-identification, novel, space-exploration

my first question here, so forgive me if I do it wrong:

I would like to find the name of a Sci-Fi book I read over 30 years ago (possibly 40)

Author: he was some kind of military strategist i think. At least that is how the book reads.

Plot and Setting: Their ship lands on an alien planet and they set up to look around and find out if there are alien species.

They find deep potholes filled with water in the surface and there seem to be some kind of (large lizard-like creature?) animal that ends up stalking them (I think at night). The creatures, as I remember, are SUPER fast runners, like freakishly fast.   The science guy (lead?) is the military minded one (i seem to remember) but he is more of a loner. He finally finds these creatures and then figures out a way to destroy them. He shares this discovery with his team, but they discount his knowledge. The team actually thinks he is a crackpot and ties him down to a gurney. At night, one of the creatures actually breaks in and almost kills him. He then goes out on his own and starts blowing up the creatures in the deep potholes.  I think at near the end, they find out that these creatures actually were needed to cull other "monsters" on the planet that were even worse. (or something like this)

Anyone have any idea?  I'd love to read it again...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sounds like *The Legacy of Heorot* by Larry Niven and Jerry Pournelle. More details in the previously asked questions

- [A planet where killing a monster brought even worse devastation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260097/a-planet-where-killing-a-monster-brought-even-worse-devastation/)
- [Colonists kill local creature, only to discover they were killing off immature monsters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142303/colonists-kill-local-creature-only-to-discover-they-were-killing-off-immature-m/)
- (and other questions)

Comment: Sequels dropped off _fast_, IMO.

Comment: Yeah, this is absolutely Legacy of Heorot.

Comment: The "master" question seems to be https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/33195/28516

Comment: Thank you all! Yes, this is it!!

Comment: Damn, I have to stop wasting the time to get quotes and write up a proper answerml.